# Itunes Keeps deleting my podcasts

Tags: itunes, ipod, podcasts, macos

I like to download podcasts to my ipod to listen to them at work or at the gym. However, after I have listened to them, once I sync my ipod with my computer, it deletes the podcasts that I have played from both my computer and my ipod, despite the fact i have the settings set to not delete them automatically after they have been played. I like to keep old podcasts of some shows (such as This American Life) because once they add the new episode to itunes, the old one is only accessible through purchase and I want to save them in case i want to listen to them again. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Haven't experienced this particular bug but I'm finding iTunes more and more flakey with every release. Maybe you could right click on the podcast (before it disappears), show it in the finder and make a copy to a backup folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. For me I found a "refresh" button in the title of the podcast, then the episodes were visible again and I could right-click/highlight and select 'mark as unplayed' It seems to be working for me :)